# Built in Self Test - In Embedded memories

Tags: embedded, memory, software, test, flash-memories

I am reading this thing called -BIST (Built in Self Test).

I understand that, before a module enters its intended functionality, this BIST is made to run within the module. Once, this BIST is passed, then, the module is allowed to RUN. Am I correct?

I just want to understand, how this BIST is implemented in Software? Like specifically, what happens during this BIST test with respect to Embedded memories in an Module?

Comment: This type of  broad question does not really fit within the mission of this site.  Generally speaking, the types of memories most likely to have some sort of self-test feature are those like high density NAND flash where defects and aging are inescapable.  That implicitly requires a flash translation layer, which is a logical place to put a test routine.  The flash translation layer might be implemented on a dedicated processor in different die in a hybrid package (SD/eMMC), a distinct chip (USB stick, SSD), even in host processor software (some embedded systems).

Comment: I tried internet searches for this topic. I couldn't find that many. Could you comment a link which would help a beginner like me in this topic

Answer (score 0):

BIST is certainly not a new thing. You should be able to find a great deal of information if you do an internet search.

The software for testing embedded memories depends on the kind of memory. Non-volatile, preprogrammed memory can be tested with checksums. RAM is tested by writing various patterns to the memory and reading the results back. The choice of the best patterns to use depends on how the memory is physically constructed and organized.

Comment: Thank you. So, My understand of BIST is correct, right? - "before a module enters its intended functionality, this BIST is made to run within the module. Once, this BIST is passed, then, the module is allowed to RUN"

Comment: And is BIST only applicable to memories or where else is it applicable?

Comment: BIST is applicable to all kinds of digital systems. BIST can be designed to run off-line, as you describe, before a system starts running or it can be designed to run continuously as a background task. This is really a very broad area.